# How to set focus automatically to the subgrid row in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, subgrid

I am Dynamically adding row in subgrid of jqgrid. After adding I want to set focus automatically to that new row which is being added in the subgrid. I am using asp.net. How could i achieve this.. Please help me out..

Comment: Asp.NET doesn't matter... It's JQuery which is an 'extension' of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution using the edit row function in Jqgrid.. The syntax is as follows:

```
$("#grid_id").editRow(rowid, keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);
```

For details check http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Answer (score 0):

if you can get newest added row

if you are adding newest row to last use this

```
$('#grid tr:last').focus();
```

if you are adding newest row to first use this

```
$('#grid tr:first').focus();
```

Comment: Its actually a subgrid. So how could i do so in subgrid?